# How to open subfiles in a master file by right clicking them in TeXworks?

Tags: texworks

I miss a functionality in TeXworks. When working on a master file in LaTeX that includes subfiles by means of the `\input{\pathToFile/filename.tex}` command, I would like the possibility of right clicking on the `"filename.tex"` to open this file. This functionality is available when editing MatLab files and is extremely handy and practical. Is there some script available for TeXworks that makes this possible? Or, are there other LaTeX editors that make this possible?

Comment: Google is your friend: http://code.google.com/p/texworks/issues/detail?id=261#c5

Comment: Please accept an answer if your question has been addressed to your satisfaction. (If not, tell us why!) People donate their time to your questions and not accepting an answer gives the impression that you don't appreciate their contributions.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel That link should point to github these days. See my edit to your answer ...

Answer (score 2):

The project page of TeX Works has a collection of available scripts.

One script has the following description:

> When using a master document, you may wish to open a selected file
>   name, or one in  an `\input{filename.tex}` just position the cursor
>   between the `{braces}` (useful until  project management tools are able
>   to be developed)

The script: [openFileAtInputTag.zip](https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/261#issuecomment-80296461)

Comment: Thanks. I have downloaded, unzipped and put the .js file into the scripts folder. However, when placing the cursor and chosing the script from the Scripts menu, I get the following error message: "Uncaught exception at C:/Users/espen.donali/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/TeXworks/0.4/scripts/Acona commands/openFileAtInputTag.js:23: SyntaxError: Parse error". What is wrong?

Comment: @EspenDonali The script contains errors. Some comments have no comment marker, and it also tries to use a function which, according to the docs, "was removed in late 2010".